# Drag-and-drop view-элементов LinearLayout - как менять порядок view-элементов

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, drag-n-drop

Имеется LinearLayout, а на нём элементы TextView. Каждому элементу TextView присвоен обработчик

```
    ... new View.OnTouchListener() {

            int initialX = 0;
            int initialY = 0;
            static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
            long startClickTime;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = (int) event.getX();
                        initialY = (int) event.getY();
                        startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (clickDuration > MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                            int currentX = (int) event.getX();
                            int currentY = (int) event.getY();
                            dcl.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "(%d,%d)", currentX, currentY));
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) v.performClick();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

В идеале планирую при отпускании пальца ставить элемент, где был начат Drag-and-drop перед элементом, до которого он был протянут, но пока я просто вывожу координаты, проверяя работу Listener'а.

Проблема в том, что когда палец покидает пределы исходного элемента, в том числе переходя на другой элемент TextView, обработчик перестает работать (в данном "предварительно-отладочном" примере координаты перестают обновляться), при этом запускается прокручивание ScrollView, который содержит этот LinearLayout с элементами.

Как сделать так, чтобы перетаскивание было возможно и при покидании исходного элемента, а прокручивание осуществлялось только при зажимании пальца на свободном месте ScrollView'а от элементов TextView? Ещё при коротком нажатии нужно сохранить OnClick TextView'а, но с этим я более-менее разобрался, и за это отвечает строка:

```
if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) v.performClick();
```

PS. Я в курсе, что это было бы проще сделать, используя DragListView, но в данном случае это невозможно. LinearLayout, на котором сидят TextView'хи является частью компонента, унаследованного глубоко по иерархии, и поменять LinearLayout на ListView нельзя, т.к. разрушатся другие компоненты этой иерархии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил это следующим способом:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    scrollView = null;
    ViewParent parent = this;
    while (parent != null && !(parent instanceof ScrollView)) parent = parent.getParent();
    if (parent != null) scrollView = (ScrollView) parent;
}

private int displayHeight;
private ScrollView scrollView;
private boolean scrollDisabled = false;

private void disableScrolling() {
    if (scrollView != null) scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    scrollDisabled = true;
}

private void enableScrolling() {
    if (scrollView != null) scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    scrollDisabled = false;
}

private void scrollDynamically(int posY) {
    if (scrollView == null) return;
    int[] layoutOnScreen = new int[2];
    mLayout.getLocationOnScreen(layoutOnScreen);
    //здесь и в дальнейшем mLayout - LinearLayout, на котором размещены перетаскиваемые элементы
    if (layoutOnScreen[1] < 240 && posY < 300) scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, posY < 200 ? -20 : -10);
    if (posY > displayHeight - 150) scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, posY > displayHeight - 50 ? 20 : 10);
}


private void init() {
    //здесь определяется высота дисплея
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (windowManager == null) return;
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    displayHeight = size.y;
    mLayout.setPadding(2, 4, 2, 20);
}

private final OnTouchListener DRAG_AND_DROP = new OnTouchListener() {

    long startClickTime;
    TextView target = null;
    TextView source = null;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                source = (TextView) v;
                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (clickDuration > MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    if (!scrollDisabled) disableScrolling();
                    target = null;
                    for (int i = mLayout.getChildCount(); i >= 0; --i) {
                        View anyChild = mLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        if (anyChild instanceof TextView) {
                            TextView child = (TextView) anyChild;
                            Rect bounds = new Rect();
                            child.getHitRect(bounds);
                            if (bounds.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) target = child;
                            else if (child != source) child.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        }
                    }
                    if (target == null) {
                        source.setTextColor(0xFF660000);
                        source.setPaintFlags(source.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    } else {
                        source.setPaintFlags(source.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        if (target != source) {
                            target.setTextColor(0xFF77FF00);
                            source.setTextColor(0xFFFF7700);
                        }
                        else source.setTextColor(0xFF77FFFF);
                    }
                    scrollDynamically((int) event.getRawY());
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) v.performClick();
                else {
                    if (target == null) /*действия при удалении*/;
                    else {
                        target.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                        if (target == source) /*действия при вставке*/;
                        else /*действия при перемещении*/;
                    }
                    source.setPaintFlags(source.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    source.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                }
                enableScrolling();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

В результате Drag-and-drop обеспечивает три функции: удаление элемента, перемещение элемента (с возможностью одновременной с перетаскиванием прокрутки, если цель перемещения находится за пределами экрана) и вставка новых элементов. При этом сохраняется onClick элемента и прокручивание ScrollView.